# How to read/write streams of ProcessBuilder and finally create a output file in ffmpeg

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to transcode a video using ffmpeg with java.ProcessBuilder. I read the other threads regarding this but it doesn't really solve my problem.

I think everything goes well up till Process p=pb.start(). I know I have to read some stream of ProcessBuilder and convert it to a byte[] and write that to a file. I thought ffmpeg would do all that for me since I'm passing the "inputFile" and OutputFile paths. Anyway I post what I have till here. How can I fix this code so that I can see a fully transcoded video file after as result?

Currently all code execute with no error and the output file is created but its size is 0KB. I'm running the code from windows server in a Java (.jar) program.

**This is a snippet of the program**

```
try {

    File encodingFile = new File("c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\output.mp4");
    File errorFile = new File("c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\error.txt");
    errorFile.createNewFile();
    encodingFile.createNewFile();

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe", "-i", "c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\input.mp4", "-y", "-s", "360" + "480" + "-1", "-vcodec", "libx264", "c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\output.mp4"); //or other command....
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pb.redirectError(errorFile);
    //pb.redirectOutput(encodingFile);

    Process p=pb.start();
    byte[] videoIn;
    File file = new File("c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\input.mp4");
    videoIn = new byte[(int)file.length()];

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    fileInputStream.read(videoIn);
           */
    gui.textArea1.append("\n+++++++Finished while converting!++++++++\n");

}catch(IOException ex){
    gui.textArea1.append("\nIOException converting: "+ex.getMessage());
}finally{
    try{
        if(is!=null){
            is.close();
        }
        if(fos!=null){
            fos.close();
        }
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        gui.textArea1.append("\nClosing streams while converting:"+ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
gui.textArea1.append("converting finished!");
```

Comment: Why do you redirect stderr to stdout? And only _after_ that you redirect it to a file?

Comment: I saw that from someones code. What must I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
pb.redirectError(errorFile);
//pb.redirectOutput(encodingFile);
```

What you are doing here is redirect stderr to stdout; and both are redirected to `errorFile`.

And your `encodingFile` is just created with:

encodingFile.createNewFile();

which is not even guaranteed to succeed.

Fix:

```
final Path videoIn = Paths.get("c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\input.mp4");
final Path encodingFile = Paths.get("c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\output.mp4");
final Path errorFile = Paths.get("c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\error.txt");

int retCode;

try {
    Files.deleteIfExists(encodingFile);
    Files.deleteIfExists(errorFile);

    final ProcessBuilder pb 
        = new ProcessBuilder("c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe",
            "-i", videoIn.toString(),
            "-y", 
            "-s", "360x480", // stripped the extraneous "-1"
            "-vcodec", "libx264",                    
            "c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\output.mp4"
    ); //or other command....

    pb.redirectError(errorFile.toFile());
    pb.redirectOutput(encodingFile.toFile());

    final Process p = pb.start();

    // CHECK FOR THIS!
    retcode = p.waitFor();

    // Reproduced here; not sure this is anything useful,
    // since the old code, just like this one, just reads the contents
    // from the video file to be converted... Huh?
    final byte[] videoIn = Files.readAllBytes(videoIn);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // deal with e here
}
```

Note about the original code:

- why are you reading the contents of the original video file? It does not make sense;
- you didn't check for the return values for `.createNewFile()`; it can fail; here I use java.nio.file, this will throw an exception on error;
- you didn't check for the process' return code; here it is in a `retCode` variable which you MUST check afterwards. For possible error codes, refer to the ffmpeg man page.

Comment: thanks:-) I receiving perfect/desired output. I'm using your code now. I love your answer.

Comment: I hope you get this: I tried to scale to "240x320" but the resulting video is bigger than that. Maybe it's the command, maybe there's something missing. How can I scale to a specific resolution like "240x320" and have it come out the other side like that? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea... I don't use ffmpeg :p I just looked up the manpage to have a working command line for you but that's about it.

Comment: this code is working without the call to:  final byte[] videoIn = Files.readAllBytes(videoIn); Hi. can you help me understand bitrate and fps? Sending a video-clip from one mobile device to another one, making sure (<transcoder>) convert the file so it will look the best it can on that specific device in terms of quality/video/sound. Thank you.